# Is there a way to display a field of a map[key-string] with value-struct, in html, in golang?

Tags: go, go-html-template

I have a datatype of map[key-string] value-struct, and I'm trying to display a field(Timing) of the struct

I tried all sort of variations for an hour, can't seem to figure it out. Would appreciate any guidance on this, thank you!

Also apologies on the formatting, am new, do bear with me!
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Csyv.png)

Comment: `$value` or `.` in the outer `range` will be the map values, the struct values. Remove the inner `range`. Please include the code how you execute the template. Also don't post links to images, include all code and template in the question. A link to a runnable example on the [Go playground](https://go.dev/play/) is also welcome.

Comment: If the values stored in map are not structs having a `Timing` field, you also need to post what they are. Anyway, aim for a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of inner loop, use {{$value.Timing}}.

```
// You can edit this code!
// Click here and start typing.
package main

import (
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

type A struct {
    Timing string
}

func main() {
    inp := `
    <html>
    
    {{ range $key,$value:= .}}
        Key:{{$key}}, Timing {{$value.Timing}}
    {{end}}
    </html>
`
    valueMap := map[string]A{
        "key": A{
            Timing: "1",
        },
    }
    t, err := template.New("test").Parse(inp)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = t.Execute(os.Stdout, valueMap)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. I changed to {{$value.Timing}} but it is still not showing anything after the first line

Comment: Hello again! I missed out the Caps for the field in struct declaration, it works, thank you!!